# How to export ConvNet trained using Python's Theano/Lasagne to iOS?

Tags: python, ios, theano, conv-neural-network, lasagne

I trained a convolutional neural net with Lasagne and Theano frameworks on Python.

I am satisfied with the architecture and the performance of the net on test data and I want to use it on an iPad application.

I was wondering if there is any simple way to take that net and use it on iOS without rewriting the code in another framework and/or train it again?

As far a I know, there is no way to convert the Python code directly to c/c++ (which might be a method for exporting the net/training code).